# How to get week number from a date

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to get the week number from a specific date
Like so
if project start date is 01-12-2020,
and today is 14-12-2020

the current week number is **2**

thanks

Comment: I dont know php but my view is have a count variable .Subtract 7 from that date if the subtracted value is not negative then increment count variable(put that in loop) .

Answer (score 0):

use this First get 1day of a date and get its week no cuz php provide year week no.
now get current date week no and subtract it you will get the current week no:

```
$month= (date('Y-m-01'));
$yearweek = date('W');
$monthweek = date('W',strtotime($month));
echo  $yearweek - $monthweek;
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate how many weeks there are between two dates.
To do this, calculate the difference in days and divide that by 7.
The week number (Project week) is then the whole part plus 1.

```
$start = date_create('01-12-2020');
$curDate = date_create('14-12-2020');
$weekNumber = (int)($start->diff($curDate)->days/7)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with :

```
$now = Carbon::now();
echo $now->weekOfYear;
```